# BitLocker Protection Off?

Tags: windows, bitlocker

`manage-bde` is reporting `Protection Status:    Protection Off`

[image]

I'm guessing that this means that BitLocker has been suspended but, even after researching this online, it's unclear exactly what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Protection Off` does indeed mean that BitLocker has been suspended, as confirmed by using commands `Suspend-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -RebootCount 0` and `Resume-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:"`

[image]